# Unable to decode the token in React Native using jwt-decode

Tags: react-native, token, asyncstorage

` LOG  Token from AsyncStorage: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NWI3YTNmZDQ1ZGI1MjQ1MDRlMzhkMGMiLCJpYXQiOjE3MTA3ODM3NzZ9._CWFhpej9GbBbzNlQTU48I575uVuKmLBMohLOdkftZ0
LOG  Decoded Token: false
LOG  User ID: undefined
LOG  Final User ID: undefined

im getting the token in the response but unable  to decode the token...its showing undefined

im using jwtDecode to decode the Token`